# Does changing datatype of a field in Oracle DB hurts the performance

Tags: oracle

I have a need to change a Numeric(3) field into Varchar2(3) field, A java program communicates with the DB and we want to differentiate between 01 and 1 that is the reason for change. and we are worried that this could affect the indexing and peformance of Oracle. I'm not a Oracle DBA and so I have no / little knowledge on performace related area.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: We cannot answer this. We cannot possibly know if the statements you use include implicit data conversions at runtime. Why don't you just change it on your test database and test it?

Comment: The real question is why must you change the type?  If it's really a number, you should be able to model and use it as such.  If it's a string, you shouldn't have to convert.  You can index on varchar columns.  Sounds like incorrect advice to me.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks, one more clarification - will existing data be converted for more and stored as varchar2 or will be internally converted everytime I query for it?

Comment: How many records does this table have?

Comment: 31 column filled to 752897491 rows @nvoigt second busiest in our application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Number(3)` takes 3 bytes, `Varchar2(3)` takes 3 bytes, so records would stay in the same blocks, therefore:

If your column is not indexed then indexes will be fine. If column was indexed, then index should be recreated anyway.

To minimize offline time you might go with CTAS/rename aproach:

```
create table new_table as select ... from old_table
```

build whatever indexes you need on a new_table
then 
rename new_table to old_table

dependent views/procedures would be rebuilt and reloaded to shared pool.

If your tables apraching 1 billion, it is time get DBA :)

Comment: The storage required by a value in a `number` column is not determined by the defined length but by the actual value stored in the column. A `number(22)` will take the same amount of space as a `number(3)` if they both store the same values. A `varchar2(3)` can actually use up to 9 bytes depending on the character set and the data in it.

Comment: Hmm.. agree, it is easy to think just about english. But if they will store only numbers, will they go over 3 bytes?